# Hide an empty list of filtered items with Handlebars

Tags: html, handlebars.js

### Goal

In Handlebars, hide a list of filtered items (including its heading) if the list is empty.

### Current code (without logic to hide the filtered list if empty)

```
{{#if workItems}}

# Fabric
## New
{{#filter 'fabric-new'}}
{{#workItems}}
{{{ field-html 'Platform.ReleaseNote' }}}
{{/workItems}}
{{/filter}}

## Fixed
{{#filter 'fabric-known'}}
{{#workItems}}
{{{ field-html 'Platform.ReleaseNote' }}}
{{/workItems}}
{{/filter}}

{{else}}
{{/if}}
```

#### Returns

```
# Fabric
## New
Release Note
Release Note
Release Note

## Fixed
```

The empty `## Fixed` section in the output is expected because no items are returned with the filter in the `## Fixed` section.

### Desired output

I want to apply the logic that if no items are returned with the filter in the `## Fixed` section, the `## Fixed` section, including its heading, is hidden.

```
# Fabric
## New
Release Note
Release Note
Release Note
```

(As a secondary goal that may be out of the scope of this question, I would like to hide the entire `# Fabric` section and its heading if *both* the `## New` and `## Fixed` sections are empty.)

### Attempt 1

I was advised that this is the direction I should go to hide empty sections if a list of items is empty.

```
{{#if fabric.workItems}}

 # Known issues
{{#fabric.workItems}}
{{{ field-html 'Platform.ReleaseNote' }}}
{{/fabric.workItems}}

{{/if}}
```

#### Failure

My attempt to implement this advice hides the `New` section even though the filter returns items. (`Fixed` is not included in this example, because `New` failed and I didn't proceed.)

```
{{#if workItems}}

## Fabric
{{#if new.workItems}}

### New
{{#filter 'fabric-new'}}
{{#new.workItems}}
{{{ field-html 'Platform.ReleaseNote' }}}
{{/new.workItems}}
{{/filter}}
{{/if}}

{{else}}
{{/if}}
```

I tried several unsuccessful iterations but will not make this question unnecessarily long by including all of them, unless someone requests that.

I am only beginning to learn Handlebars and would be grateful for any support in my pursuit of a solution or directions to documentation that guides me to an answer. If critical information is missing from my question, I apologize and will supply it. Thank you.